# Quartz Scheduler not starting instantly

Tags: quartz.net

After creating New Quartz by (Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET)
with With Cron Schedule, the `NextFireTimeUtc` will start one hour after. How can I set it that start instantly?

```
TriggerBuilder triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder
            .Create()
            .WithIdentity(TriggerName, GroupeId)
            .WithPriority(1)
            .StartNow();


        StringBuilder interval;

        string cronExpression = default(string);

        interval = new StringBuilder();

        switch (ruleScheduler.Schedulers.IntervalUnitType)
        {
            case Scheduler.IntervalUnitTypeInfo.Minute:
                {
                    interval.Append(string.Format("0 0/{0}", ruleScheduler.Schedulers.Interval));
                    break;
                }
            case Scheduler.IntervalUnitTypeInfo.Second:
                {
                    interval.Append(string.Format("0/{0} 0", ruleScheduler.Schedulers.Interval));
                    break;
                }
        }

        if (ruleScheduler.Schedulers.StartTimeOfDay.HasValue)
        {
            interval.Append(string.Format(" {0}", ruleScheduler.Schedulers.StartTimeOfDay.Value.Hour));

            if (ruleScheduler.Schedulers.EndTimeOfDay.HasValue)
            {
                interval.Append(string.Format("-{0}", ruleScheduler.Schedulers.EndTimeOfDay.Value.Hour));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            interval.Append("*");
        }

        string dayOfWeek = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ruleScheduler.Schedulers.DaysOfWeek) ? "?" : ruleScheduler.Schedulers.DaysOfWeek.ToString();

        cronExpression = string.Format("{0} * * {1} *", interval.ToString(), dayOfWeek);

        triggerBuilder.WithCronSchedule(cronExpression);

        trigger = triggerBuilder.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should rewrite your trigger building code like this:

```
TriggerBuilder triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder
            .Create()
            .WithIdentity(TriggerName, GroupeId)
            .WithPriority(1)
            .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression)
            .Build();
```

Then you pass the trigger to the Scheduler:

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, triggerBuilder );
```